# call a method of a static instance in EJB

Tags: java, static, ejb, instance-variables, simultaneous-calls

I have a guess that there is an incorrect code in our codebase but I am not sure. So we have got en EJB like this:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEjb {
  private static Something sg = new Something();
  public void doSomething() {
    sg.execute();
  }
}
```

The class Something is a normal class:

```
public class Something {
  public void execute() {
    ...
  }
}
```

As the MyEJB is stateless EJB so the method doSomething can be called more times simultaneously.

Here comes my questions: if the doSomething() has been called twice at the same time then one of the calls will be blocked until the first call finishes? My guess is that it is blocked as there is just one static instance.
If I am right the code above is not good as the method 'execute' of class 'Something' is a bottleneck for my EJB.

Thanks,
V.

Comment: Just a note, I don't think the whole EJB part is relevant at all here, we just have a normal static instance of a class, the scenario would be the same if myEJB was a normal class.

Comment: Hi Rasmus, That's right. The reason why I mentioned the EJB was to emphasize that there is just one JVM. However you are right, not the EJB is important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both calls will run simultaneously, unless you restrict the access using a "synchronized" block or a "Write Lock".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I don't understand is that we are in the same JVM so the Something class has got just one instance. How is it possible that a method of one instance is able to run more times simultaneously...? Or am I at a loss completely? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% on the details so call me out if I'm wrong here. The code in methods are not stored per instance, but rather somewhere in the classloader, ONCE. Regardless of static or not. This is why object instances aren't larger just because they contain more code. You don't need an "instance" of a method to execute it, multiple threads can execute the code in the same method at the same time, local variables are however stored per thread in its stack. Synchronized should only be needed when the method uses a shared resource, for example a class variable or file IO.